# Error when starting vim

Tags: python, vim, omnicomplete

I am getting the following error on vim startup:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>71_OnBufferRead..<SNR>71_SetOmnicompleteFunc..<SNR>71_Pyeval: line    2: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi/model.py:532: UserWarning: 'point_conversion_form_t' has no values explicitly defined; guessing that it is  equivalent to 'unsigned int'   % self._get_c_name())
```

Anyone know a quick fix?

Comment: Edit: Here's my .vimrc: https://github.com/upgrd/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc

Comment: Did you compile YouCompleteMe?

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to assess, but after a quick look at your vimrc I would venture to guess that this is caused by the currently not working combination of python3+YCM. The best fix would be to use Jedi for the time being.

Comment: Re-installed + compiled YCM. The initial error message is gone, but got a new one: `Error detected while processing function <SNR>123_OnCursorMovedNormalMode..<SNR>123_OnFileReadyToParse..<SNR>123_Pyeval:
line    4:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi/model.py:532: UserWarning: 'point_conversion_form_t' has no values explicitly defined; guessing that it is
 equivalent to 'unsigned int'
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function <SNR>123_OnCursorMovedNormalMode..<SNR>123_OnFileReadyToParse..<SNR>123_Pyeval:
line    4:
  % self._get_c_name())

Comment: you should follow the advice in [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file) and start vim using `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N` to find out where the error is coming from.